# Talend: How can I set global variable into tREST HTTP Body?

Tags: rest, http, post, talend

I am developing a new REST webservice for our application.
My goal is to pass instead of the fixed date, a date that I retrieve from a database ,
but as I report in the images below the parameter does not work correctly.
While if I pass the date as per the field below the job works correctly.
Would you know how to help me.
Thank you

"
{
"tokenKey": "ofsodfdsnsd frrfmoic",
"dbKey": "dd_ab",
"customerKey": "lp_ProdG100",
"from":"2022-11-01",
"period": "DAY",
"profile": 1
}
"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your body

`"{\r\n  \"tokenKey\": \"your token \",\r\n  \"dbKey\": \"dbKey\",\r\n  \"customerKey\": \"customerKey\",\r\n  \"from\": \""+((Date)globalMap.get("row93.oggi"))+"\",\r\n  \"period\": \"period\",\r\n  \"profile\": 1 \r\n} "`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I modified the code but no data is returned.

Comment: all values are null ?

Comment: try after tflowtoiterate to put a tJava

Comment: in the tJava : String Body = "{\r\n  \"tokenKey\": \"your token \",\r\n  \"dbKey\": \"dbKey\",\r\n  \"customerKey\": \"customerKey\",\r\n  \"from\": \""+((Date)globalMap.get("row93.oggi"))+"\",\r\n  \"period\": \"period\",\r\n  \"profile\": 1 \r\n} " ;

Comment: System.out.println(Body) ;

Comment: desactivate tRest and all the other components after it ;)

Comment: Thank you, I will try. I think the problem is because it is returning me an incorrect date format, even though I specify the format in the sql code.

Comment: SELECT distinct
 DATE_FORMAT(date,\"%Y-%m-%d\") AS oggi
from calendar
where 
date ='2022-11-02

Comment: instead of just returning me '2022-11-02' it gives me '2022-11-02 00:00:00' consequently it goes into error

Comment: your Json is correct though ?

Comment: SELECT distinct SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(date,\"%Y-%m-%d\"),1,10 )AS oggi from calendar where date ='2022-11-02

Comment: in tdbinput 2 put it like a String note a date then also in the globalMap  cast it to STring

Comment: Thank you, but you expect a Date the Trest . I discovered this by running the job in Trace Debug

Comment: did you try FORMAT (date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: I think you have your answer to this topic (i corrected your globalMap variale passing into json ) you could mark solved if it helped